# How to read boolean (true/false) of all functions in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, boolean

I'm having a hard time reading the return Boolean value of a number of functions I added to an array. I want to read it such that if any of the functions in the array reads false it returns false to the parent function.

Here's a sample of the code I'm running:

```
function validate(){
    var function1 = functionA();
    var function2 = functionB();
    var function3 = functionC();
    var function4 = functionD();
    var result = new Array;
    result.push(function1);
    result.push(function2);
    result.push(function3);
    result.push(function4);
    if (result.some(false)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I get the "false is not a function" error while debugging, Is there any work around that wont totally change this structure, if not lay whatever idea you have it would still be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: `.some()` wants a callback function (which `false` is not): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because `some()` is expecting a function, not a boolean. To fix this, provide a function to that method which interrogates each element of the array and returns your required value.

Also note that the logic can be made much more succinct:

```js
function validate() {
  var result = [functionA(), functionB()];
  return !result.some(v => !v);
}

function functionA() {
  return true;
}

function functionB() {
  return false;
}

console.log(validate());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a function to `some()`

```js
function validate(){
    var function1 = functionA();
    var function2 = functionB();
    var function3 = functionC();
    var function4 = functionD();
    var result = new Array;
    result.push(function1);
    result.push(function2);
    result.push(function3);
    result.push(function4);
    if (result.some(f => !f)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
console.log(validate());
function functionA(){
  return true;
}
function functionB(){
  return false;
}
function functionC(){
  return true;
}
function functionD(){
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take the function references in an array and call them in the callback for checking.

```
function validate() {
    var conditionChecks = [functionA, functionB, functionC, functionD];
    return !conditionChecks.some(fn => fn());
}
```

Comment: thanks for the share was really insightful but following your method i would have to make another function for fn() as it isnt a function in my code, im avoiding that

Comment: `fn()` is a reference to the functionA/B/C so there's no extra code required. This is analagous to my answer, the difference is simply to point at which you invoke the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Array.some() argument should be a function.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var even = function(element) {
  // checks whether an element is even
  return element % 2 === 0;
};

console.log(array.some(even));
// expected output: true
```

Check out the docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: Worth an upvote for providing a link, but the code is just copied from the link, which is kinda sad.  Maybe you could engineer your code to match the question?

Comment: The OP mistake was simple, there's no need to resolve his specific problem. Snippet is provided only to prevent the link content to change or to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.some()
```

Expects a callback to evaluate your array, not a boolean.
If you provide it with a function like this:

```
function callback(el) {
  return el
}
```

And pass it instead of false, your example will work.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, *some* requires a function to evaluate.

```
function checkIfFalse(valToCheck){
    return valToCheck === false;
}
```

Use this function in your some call like this:

```
if (result.some(checkIfFalse)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```